# Variable not found in Robot Framework-RIDE

Tags: python-2.7, testing, automation, automated-tests, robotframework

I have a test case where I am iterating using a FOR loop, where the variable in the loop is "j".

I am then using this "j" in a user-defined keyword, but the test case fails and the error is "Variable j not found".

This exact same test case works on another machine without any error, and I'm not sure why. In my machine where it fails, there is no problem with libraries or the setup, and this variable is not being saved anywhere.

Could someone please suggest why this could happen?

Comment: please show a [mcve]. Also, please verify that the problem only appears in RIDE, or if it appears when you run the test from the command line.

Comment: It happens in both cases. If it helps, the machine in which it passes has a different version of Robot Framework-Mine has 3.0, the other has 2.8.4. Both have Python 2.7. As mentioned in the question, the code is exactly the same. Is it possible that could be the issue?

Comment: It's impossible to say whether it's possible or not without seeing actual code. I think that if there were a bug in how robot handles :FOR loops, it would have been caught before now.

Answer (score 1):

You can give variable "j" with symbol `@`